# Duplicate close vote seems to disappear if the close target is deleted?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642129/emoji-character-is-not-working-with-utf8mb4-bin) as a duplicate, as the OP had asked the exact same question 2 days ago. The OP then decided to delete [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604299/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database-with-utf8mb4-bin). (Please note links to these questions are for reproduction of the potential bug, it is not my intention to bring the wrath of meta down on this person's head!)

My close vote now no longer appears in the close link:

[image]

should be:

[image]

The comment is still there:

[image]

but the close vote *seems* to have disappeared. I can't vote to close it again:

[image]

It's unclear if my vote is not still active or not? Possible bug or expected behaviour?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yup, your close vote was automatically cleared by the system when the duplicate target was deleted. These events occurred at almost exactly the same time, down to the second.

The close vote being removed also removes the post from the closure review queue. Nobody else needs to review it for the originally flagged reason.

Overall, like Cerbrus, I'd say the behavior makes sense. Questions can't be closed as duplicates of deleted questions, and even if they *could*, that wouldn't be *useful*. So it just makes sense for that closure vote to be invalidated.

The only edge case is when it's the same user posting the same question repeatedly. In that case, they might be able to cover their tracks by deleting their previous questions. If you see something like this occurring, just raise a moderator flag on one of the questions and let us know that you've observed a disturbing pattern. We will investigate, and if we determine that your concern is valid, we'll take the appropriate action.

Your not being able to cast another close vote is also officially by design. We only let users vote to close once, whether the question is successfully closed or not. In this particular case, it might be useful for the vote to be cleared in such a way as if it had never existed at all, thus allowing you to vote to close again for a different reason. I don't know, I'd have to think through the consequences of that. Don't hold your breath, though; this would require changes to the system that I doubt will be implemented soon. Note that this would also be a situation where you could raise a custom moderator flag. Explain *exactly* what happened, *why* you can no longer vote to close, and also provide your *rationale* for why a moderator should close the question. This would address the case where the question is actually unclear or too broad, but you were just voting to close as a duplicate because it was literally the exact same question asked by the same user only a short time before.

Comment: glad I voted for you cody, your responses have been articulate, detailed and complete without being TL;DR verbose.

Comment: What happens if the close target is undeleted after the close vote is cleared? Is the close vote restored? Does the question go back to the close vote review queue?

Comment: I don't know for sure, @Nisarg, but I'm pretty sure nothing happens. Someone would have had to write code that specifically accounts for that edge case, and I doubt that anyone did.

Comment: @CodyGray: I could imagine the implementation might easily involve not clearing the close vote and on the page just checking if the duplicate is still a valid target and if not not showing it. That would mean if the question is undeleted the close vote would still be there and become visible again. I'm not sure if you are saying the close vote is removed from a position of absolute knowledge or just that observing the frontend the close vote is no longer visible... It would explain why the user is not able to VTC for a different reason though...

Comment: @Chris Internally, close votes are treated much like flags, so as a moderator, I can see the exact time that a flag on a post is dismissed (whether automatically, by a moderator, by self-retraction, or whatever means). So yeah, what you propose might work, but it isn't how it is designed. One thing to consider is the cost of the check that would be required. It'd have to be done for every 3k+ user who visits the question page, *and* each time a new item is loaded in the Close review queue. Probably too expensive.

Comment: "Your" is grammatically correct there, @o_O.

Comment: @CodyGray: Cool. Excellent points on performance and interesting insights into the mod experience. :)

Answer (score 3):

(Mostly) Expected behaviour.

We can't close questions as duplicates of deleted questions, so the close-as-duplicate-votes are removed.

The comment should probably be removed also, though...

Comment: Will the question still appear in the close queue? With what? I suppose it's not a massive deal but just wondering.

Comment: I assume not... There's no close-vote on it any more.