# Why did my close vote vanish?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

Yesterday I voted to close [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396693/regular-expression-for-word-or-abbreviation-of-same-word) question for being a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132262/regex-for-words-that-can-be-abbreviated) question. Today I refreshed my browser and noticed my vote disappeared, as well as the auto-generated 'possible duplicate of' comment.

When I re-open the 'close' dialog, it does tell me 'You voted to close this question 18 hours ago', but there is no vote count on any of the close categories.

Neither one of the two questions appears to have been edited or deleted in the meantime, so I suppose it is unrelated to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357584/duplicate-close-vote-seems-to-disappear-if-the-close-target-is-deleted) issue.

What happened?

Comment: It gives the impression that the SO user intentionally made the close votes disappear.  Always good to let them know that their behavior is being discussed at meta, done.

Comment: @HansPassant There is more to that, and that was not the usual situation for me. I spent too much time on checking both that dupe reason and my own similar answers, and the main point here is that I was not sure about which could be a better close reason. A lot of time passed between my actions, it happened that I hit close when I was still unsure of my own former solution being a better dupe reason. I reopened automatically once I realized it is not that better as I thought. I was looking after kids, and did not act as I would without kids around (edit the close reason).

Comment: I am not sure if the answer was already accepted then, but now, all I can do is cast a delete vote on the question in 2 days.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think the questions should be merged. Your answer is more elaborate than the ones on the duplicate. It has the most explanation and a demo link - I for one do not want it to go to waste.

Comment: @S.L.Barth That would be a good solution. And sorry for this. I will stop answering once I am busy with the family.

Comment: Even if a merge isn't done, the duplicates should be reversed.  A 5 year only question that has managed ~100 views a year and a combined +5 net score (on the question + all of the answers) doesn't seem to be a good duplicate target.  Age shouldn't be a factor

Comment: Closing then re-opening a regex question: Now you have two problems.

Comment: Related (on [meta.ubuntu.se]): [Why was my close vote removed and comment deleted?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17314/why-was-my-close-vote-removed-and-comment-deleted)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the explanation. You were answering questions while looking after the kids? Wow. I had always wondered to what lengths one should go to reach a 6-digit reputation.

Comment: @RuudHelderman It is Lalaloopsy time! :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew While I know of no official stand on family, I hope our community can agree that your family should come before SO. ;)

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, I have started a "new life" after this post. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It happens, this is why we can reopen, or undelete and use meta. Don't let that incident get over your head.

Comment: Please note that even if you goof up closing/re-opening (which will eventually happen to everyone doing user moderation tasks), there's plenty of other users with close/re-open privileges that can correct the mistake, so it usually ends up fine in the end.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47396693/timeline) of the question shows that it was closed, then reopened.

The binding close vote was made by a gold tag badge holder, who subsequently reopened it. 
The gold tag badge holder has explained their actions in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359626/why-did-my-close-vote-vanish#comment533866_359626) on the question above.

Comment: You should add that the question was closed and reopened in a short time period by a gold-badge holder who also has the accepted answer on the question. That has a very strange optic.

Comment: @BDL I've added the part about the binding close vote and reopen vote. I prefer to leave out the part of the accepted answer, at least for now. It's tangential to the actual question, and too likely to lead to speculation. If anyone wants to know why the gold tag badge holder did this, they'd better ask that user themselves.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I guess you are referring to the fact that with the proper batch, you can avoid attention being diverted away from your own answer; just trash any links to competitors by binding the close vote and immediately re-opening. Looks to me like a design flaw.

Comment: But the answer was provided before the question was closed.

Comment: @RuudHelderman If you see someone regularly doing this, you should flag one of the posts in question, explain the situation and let the mods take care of it. But I wouldn't be surprised if there are automated checks in place for this. Although I have been thinking that linked questions (which includes duplicates before dup closing or after reopening) aren't given enough visibility.

Comment: @BDL s/very strange/bad/

Comment: Geez @WiktorStribiżew has gold badges in at least 6 tags! :O